# React Simplified switch and conditional rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

I think I may have over complicated my implementation. It's working as expected but I feel like it can be optimized or implemented better.

I have on object that contains:

```
status = {
   loginError = false,
   ErrorReason = ""
}
```

In my form, I use the `status` object to render components to handle any error.

```
const Form = props => {
   const { loginError, ErrorReason } = props
   return(
   <Form>
       {ErrorReason  === "1" && loginError && <Signup/> }
    {ErrorReason  !== "1" && loginError && <ErrorBox ErrorReason={ErrorReason } />} 
   </Form>
  )
}
```

Finally in my `ErrorBox` component. I display a dialog

```
const ErrorBox = ({ ErrorReason }) => {

  let error = {
    icon: "",
    info: "",
    color: ""
  };

  switch (loginErrorReason) {
    case "2":
      error = {
        icon: "user",
        info: "ERROR 2",
        color: "#fff"
      };
      break;
    case "3":
      error = {
        icon: "password",
        info: "ERROR 3,
        color: "#000"
      };
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  return (
      <div>
        <Icon
          type={error.icon}
          style={{ fontSize: 22, marginRight: 12, color: `${error.color}` }}
        />
        {error.info}
      </div>
  );
};
```

Is there a better way to handle these errors or write the whole implementation in a shorter and more elegant manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The status object:

```
status = {
   loginError: false,
   errorReason: ''
}
```

The Form:

```
const MyForm = props => {
   const { loginError, errorReason } = props
   return(
   <Form>
       {loginError && (
          errorReason  === "1" ?  <Signup/> : <ErrorBox errorReason={errorReason} />
       )}
   </Form>
  )
}
```

ErrorBox component:

```
const ErrorBox = ({ errorReason }) => {

  let error = {
    icon: "",
    info: "",
    color: ""
  };

  if(errorReason === "2") {
      error = {
        icon: "user",
        info: "ERROR 2",
        color: "#fff"
      };
  } else if(errorReason === "3") {
      error = {
        icon: "password",
        info: "ERROR 3",
        color: "#000"
      };
  }

  return (
      <div>
        <Icon
          type={error.icon}
          style={{ fontSize: 22, marginRight: 12, color: `${error.color}` }}
        />
        {error.info}
      </div>
  );
};
```

Or

```
const errorsList = [
  { icon: "", info: "", color: ""},
  { icon: "user", info: "ERROR 2", color: "#fff" },
  { icon: "password", info: "ERROR 3", color: "#000" }
];

const ErrorBox = ({ errorReason }) => {

  const error = errorsList[+errorReason - 1] || errorsList[0];

  return (
      <div>
        <Icon
          type={error.icon}
          style={{ fontSize: 22, marginRight: 12, color: `${error.color}` }}
        />
        {error.info}
      </div>
  );
};
```

**Demo**:

[image: Edit upbeat-brook-g544c]

Comment: Any difference between using useState and just making an object?

Comment: Ah right okay I will useState. Is there any better way to handle error in ErrorBox? If not I will stick with a switch statement

Comment: I've added another possible implementation of `ErrorBox`

Comment: setState seems to cause "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."

Comment: You must rename the Form component, I've added a working example

Answer (score 0):

Your status object is invalid -- it should not have `=` for assignment. Your status object should be:

```
status = {
   loginError: false,
   ErrorReason: null
}
```

In your form you could do:

```
<Form>
  {loginError ? (
    <>
      {ErrorReason  === "1" ? (
        <Signup/>
      ) : (
        <ErrorBox ErrorReason={ ErrorReason } />
      )}
    </>
  ) : (
      //not login error
  )}
</Form>
```

Your ErrorBox component seems okay. You don't need the default clause in your switch block unless you plan on doing something there.

```
const ErrorBox = ({ ErrorReason }) => {

  let error = {
    icon: "",
    info: "",
    color: ""
  };

  switch (loginErrorReason) {
    case "1":
      error = {
        icon: "user",
        info: "ERROR 1",
        color: "#fff"
      };
      break;
    case "2":
      error = {
        icon: "password",
        info: "ERROR 2,
        color: "#000"
      };
      break;
  }

  return (
      <div>
        <Icon
          type={error.icon}
          style={{ fontSize: 22, marginRight: 12, color: `${error.color}` }}
        />
        {error.info}
      </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Any suggestions on improving handling errors in ErrorBox?